# ExecuterService hanged

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

I am facing some issue where executer service gets hanged up.

I wanted to test some scenario where one of runnable thread gets stuck as it involves with lot of systems and ultimately leads to executer hangup.

For that I created one testing scenerio where i created 5 threads through executer service and write an infinite loop in one of the thread.I see the code is getting stuck in that loop and not comming to shutdown/shoutDownNow method of main thread. What will be the priority of the main thread execution. How can we enforce shutdown in this case?

Comment: If you have your tasks inside `Executor` doing things which could require clean-up in case some task hanged or looped forever, place clean-up code in a shutdown hook.

Answer (score 1):

We can not enforce shut down until any of the runnable task is still in progress (non-daemon thread). You can try loop with large iterations and see. eg.

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
e.execute(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i =0 ; i< 5000; i++){
    System.out.println("run me in a different thread" + i);
    }

}
});
e.shutdown();
```

Comment: @thomas Actually my runnable task is interacting with different systems as a part of functionality. We don't which block of code will take more time to respond.In that situation is there a way to assign time limit for individual threads?

Comment: @Apt I did not provide the answer to your question, I just edited it for formatting.